# Serving build, `module.exports` is not modifiable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

During development, I can freely do:

**Getters.js**

```
let Getters = {}
Getters.foo = function(){ return 1; } 
Getters.bar = function(){ return 2; }
module.exports = Getters;
```

But after `npm run build` and `serve -s build -l 4000`, I get the error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'
    at Module.<anonymous> (Getters.js:954)
```

Is there an easy way to resolve this?

**EDIT**

The file that imports Getters.js is AbstractNavBar.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useStore, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { selectNavMenuItem } from './ActionCreators';

let Getters = require('./Getters');

function AbstractNavBar( { options, name } ){

  let active = useSelector( state => 
    Getters.getActiveMenuItem( state, name )
  )
  let dispatch = useDispatch();
  let items = options.map(
    item => (
      <li class="nav-item">
      <a id={name+'-'+item.href}
      class={"nav-link" + (item.href === active ? " active " : "")} 
      href="#" 
      onClick={e=>{
    dispatch(selectNavMenuItem( name, item.href ))}}>
      {item.label}
      </a>
      </li>
    )
  )
  return (
    <div class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    { items }
    </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default AbstractNavBar;
```

I should note that the code works ***perfectly fine*** on the development server, but just stops working after build then serve.

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4039

Comment: How is this relevant?

Comment: Have you checked the webpack docs? https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/

Comment: can you post the file code which you import and use `Getters` module ?

Comment: @KhanhLeTran, file added